# what is the significance and use of snapshot file in kafa data directory?

Tags: apache-kafka

I am looking at kafa data dir and I see there are several *.snapshot files (00000offset.snapshot). While I understand what the other files (like *.log, *.index, *.timestamp) in the data dir are used for - it is not clear what is the use of snapshot file. And what data does the snapshot file have (format and fields).

I found this article - [Understanding Kafka's Internal Storage and Log Retention](https://www.conduktor.io/blog/understanding-kafkas-internal-storage-and-log-retention).
It says -

> snapshot file - contains a snapshot of the producer state regarding
> sequence IDs used to avoid duplicate records. It is used when, after a
> new leader is elected, the preferred one comes back and needs such a
> state to become a leader again. This is only available for the active
> segment (log file).

The above is definitely not clear. If there are n-producers pushing to the topic, will the snapshot file have a sqeuence ID for each producer. And how does it use this ID to avoid duplicates.

Comment: I assume this refers to transactional producers, where yes, there's sequence ids for each client. You could look at the Kafka source code to find file format and fields, if you really want to

Comment: @OneCricketeer - i am not sure if its required for only transactional producers as I do not have access to a cluster. But will be great if someone else can confirms this.

Comment: You could run Kafka locally, no? Or source code is on Github, as mentioned.